# joining outputs in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below and I want to join all the outputs into a single line - so the output would look something like:

TCPIP.sys version is $one "." $two "." $three "." $four

I try and join them in powershell but I get the below error:

> PS C:\Windows> $one = (get-childitem c:\windows\system32
>   \drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart | fl *
>
> PS C:\Windows> $two = (get-childitem
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart |
>   fl *
>
> PS C:\Windows> $three = (get-childitem
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart |
>   fl *
>
> PS C:\Windows> $four = (get-childitem
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart
>   | fl *

Error:

> PS C:\Windows> write-host = $one $two
>   = Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntr yData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$one = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart).tostring() 

$two = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart).tostring()

$three = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart).tostring()

$four = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart).tostring()

write-host "TCPIP.sys version is $one.$two.$three.$four"
```

But this do the same in one line:

```
$a = (get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
write-host "TCPIP.sys version is $a"
```

Comment: btw - I am doing the above as "ProductVersion" number is different to what the GUI reports when you right-click the driver file. Weird why Powershell does not report the same numbers - I am looking for the ProductPrivatePart - but that is just a number and don't want to confuse the customer so putting it into a "nice" format for them

Comment: for me it's the same value via powershell or via rightcliking on tcpip.sys.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to query tcpip.sys four times. You can get the info from the ProductVersion property:

```
(get-childitem $env:windir\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductVersion
```

You could also use the Join operator:

```
$one,$two,$three,$four -join '.'
```